# Deleted foreign key reference, still get error when deleting

Tags: sql, sql-server, foreign-keys

I have a web app that calls an sql script that is trying to delete a row from table_1.  However, table_2 references it with an FK constraint, so this was giving an error.  I manually deleted the referencing row of table_2.  (I confirmed via query that it's gone.)  Then I ran the app and I *still* get the same error! (`The DELETE statement conflicted with the REFERENCE constraint "table_2_fk". The conflict occurred in database "my_db", table "table_2", column 'table_1_pk'.`

Why?

**Table info**

table_2 has columns pk, name, and table_1_pk. It has an FK constraint table_2_fk that ensures that table_1_fk = table_1.pk

table_1 has pk, a bunch of other columns, and no FK constraint.

**details of delete and query**

Suppose that table_1.pk = 1.  I ran the statement

```
delete from table_2 where table_1_pk = 1
```

I then queried the db:

```
select * from table_2 where table_1_pk = 1
```

This returned 0 results.

Comment: We need more information about your table definitions.

Comment: Please give more details about deleting child rows and query that confirmed they were gone.

Comment: The constraint error occurs because there is still a value that is referenced in `table_2`.  Simple as that.

Comment: There doesn't appear to be anything there.  How do I get rid of it?

Comment: Are you sure there is not another FK on that table that is holding that record?

Comment: Maybe the delete from table_2 was not committed.

Comment: @paqogomez Not in the table that the error is complaining about.

Answer (score 0):

You should change your code so that you delete from table 2 first, then delete from table 1. Or optionally add a Cascade delete to you foreign key constraint (automatically deletes from table 2 when a delete is made in table 1)

```
ADD CONSTRAINT [FK_Table2_table1] FOREIGN KEY([table_1_pk]) 
REFERENCES [dbo].[table1] ([table_1_fk ])
ON DELETE CASCADE
```